# WriteWebGL in R

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to export a 3D plot that was made using the plot3d function from the rgl package using the WrtieWebGL function for web viewing. I don't really understand the example in the WriteWebGL documentation because it saves to a temp directory. Could someone please provide an example on how to use this function and/or point out my error(s) with usage? Thank you for your time and help.

```
   attach(dataset1)       
   plot3d(Days_Prep_Time,ACT_Score,Coffee,size=5,col="blue", type="s")
   writeWebGL(dir = "webGL", filename = file.path(dir, "index.html"), 
   template = system.file(file.path("WebGL", "template.html"), package = "rgl",
   snapshot = TRUE, font = "Arial")
```

I get the following error:

```
   Error in writeWebGL(dir = "webGL", filename = file.path(dir, "index.html"),  : 
   template ‘’ does not contain %WebGL%
   In addition: Warning message:
   In file(con, "r") :
   file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `snapshot` and `font` parameters to the `system.file` function, not the `writeWebGL` function:

```
writeWebGL(dir = "webGL", filename = file.path(dir, "index.html"), 
template = system.file(file.path("WebGL", "template.html"), package = "rgl"),
snapshot = TRUE, font = "Arial")
```

In particular, note that

```
system.file(file.path("WebGL", "template.html"), package = "rgl")
```

returns the correct path from console, whereas

```
system.file(file.path("WebGL", "template.html"), package = "rgl", snapshot = TRUE, font = "Arial")
```

returns `""`.